# Tags not working with custom post type

Tags: tags

I just made a custom post type. How do I display the Tag on the my site same as what the Post post type has?

I try this function but not work :-

```
 <?php the_tags(' ', ', ', ' '); ?>
```

In panel, i see the tags but in my site not display.

Edit :-

my code of post type :-

```
register_post_type( 'interviewdoctor',
                array( 
                 'labels' => array (
                      'name' => 'InterView',
                      'singular_name' => 'InterView',
                      'add_new' => 'Add InterView',
                      'add_new_item' => 'Add InterView',
                      'edit' => 'Edit InterView',
                      'edit_item' => 'Edit InterView',
                      'new_item' => 'Add InterView',
                      'view' => 'Edit InterView',
                      'view_item' => 'Show InterView',
                      'search_items' => 'Search',
                      'not_found' => 'Not Found',
                    ),

                '_builtin' => false,
                                'taxonomies' => array('interviewdoctor', 'post_tag'),
                'public' => true, 
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'menu_position' => 5 ,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'page',
                'menu_icon' => 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-game-icons/32/Doctor.png',
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'interviewdoctor',
                    'with_front' => false,
                    'pages' => true
                ),

                'supports'   => array(
                            'title',
                             'thumbnail',
                             'editor',
                             'date',
                              'excerpt',
                               'comments', 
                               'custom-fields', 
                               'tags')
                    ) 
                );
}
add_action('init', 'interviewdoctor');
```

Comment: Whats your code for the custom post type?

Comment: @Brad Dalton See my post

Comment: 'supports' doesn't accept date and tags.

Answer (score 3):

Tags are generally already supported and included in single CPT's so you don't need to add anything however you can use this code if you like.

Add this line to your code:

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
```

So your code will look something like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpsites_custom_post_type' );
function wpsites_custom_post_type() {

register_post_type( 'your-cpt',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => __( 'Your CPT', 'wpsites' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Your CPT', 'wpsites' ),
        ),
        'has_archive'  => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_icon'    => 'dashicons-heart',
        'public'       => true,
        'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'your-cpt', 'with_front' => false ),
        'supports'     => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies'   => array( 'your-cpt-type',  'post_tag' ),
    ));

}
```

Replace all instances of your-cpt with the name of your custom post type.

Comment: See my post, i do same thing your code but tags not display

Comment: Works for me as i tested it locally. You could use my code and replace all instances of your-cpt with the name of your custom post type

Comment: I do that but now work !!!

Comment: Ok don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @BradDalton one point to add to your answer. Had a look at the asker's code. `'supports'` doesn't accept `date` and `tags`.

Comment: Yep. Good point which is probably why it didn't work! hahaha